# In R, how to group by value sign?

Tags: r, grouping, cluster-computing

I have a `data.frame` with columns `order`, `x`, `sign`. I want to create groups by `sign` but keeping order columns. The column sign describes by `0` that `x` value is positive number, and by 1 that `x` value is a negative number or zero. The output that I want is kind of:

```
Group1: order = 0
Group2: order = 1 and 2
Group3: order = 3,4,5,6,7
Group4: order = 8,9,10,11
Group5: order = 12,13,14
Group6: order = 15
```

After that, I would like to calculate the mean of x values by my Group1,Group2....

[Table image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMPgz.png)

Comment: `data.table::rleidv(df1$sign)` - `df1` being your data.frame

Comment: [link to my data.frame figure ] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l8Qlt-w5wVrqfJw7Ygxu8K6y33O9QlMr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: why picture again? install package data.table and use rleidv.

Comment: Thanks Andre Elrico!!!!

Comment: you're welcome. rleidv will create your grouping variable then use any "group-by" functionality out there.

Comment: iT WORKS!...hOW CAN I CREATE 6 GROUPS KEEPING ORIGINAL ORDER DATA

Comment: deactivate caps lock

Comment: ¿how to use rleidv in a split data?